# Is there a way to overwrite animation transition inspector window in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

inspector overwriting works good everywhere but not in animations (can't owerwrite animation state inspector window too). Is there a way to do this?

UPD1 For example:
Default inspector:

[image: default inspector for Scripts]

overwriten inspector

[image: overwriten inspector]

I want to do similar with AnimatorStateTransition

[image]

i.e. overwrite inspector for state transition, but the simpliest way does't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by overwrite animation. Can you add example of what you mean and with screenshot of what animation you are talking about?

Comment: @Programmer i've made update for post